# Interviewer is being interviewed in my company

Tags: hiring, europe

I had an interview with a company X with different people, one of them should be my future manager in that company.

I discovered that this person is now in the hiring process in my current company for a position similar to mine, not even for being a manager or something similar.

Now that company X has sent me an offer, but to me, this event is a red flag which made me take the decision to decline that offer.

Since I guess i can't (and I don't want) mention the fact that since my future manager wants to join my current company I don't want to accept the offer,

What would be a good motivation to refuse the offer without being too generic?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to answer to why you are declining the offer? Motivations can be many, and is unique to each individual

Comment: I would like to a polite way to say "the fact that since my future manager want to join my current company I don't want to accept the offer," without mentioning it directly @DarkCygnus

Comment: You could be right in your decision but I've seen quite a few people stepping down from a management positions to become a developer again. When you are promoted to be a manager on a development team you all of a sudden have to deal with whole bunch of people's issues, meetings, plannings, budgets, other stuff and do the something you really love (software development) only 50% or less time. Some people do not realize it before trying and some know about it but think that this is what they want to do but after some time are getting completely sick of it.

Answer (score 18):

Why do you even think that this is a red flag?

The manager for example could simply have found out after a promotion that being a manager is not the right thing for her (too much stress, politics, whatever) and wants to work again as non-manager. And because stepping down in a company is not easy, she decided to go to a different company. Or something completely different that is also completely irrelevant for you.

You didn't say anything about the two companies, so I can't see any reason why you should not accept the offer.

Comment: This is a nice point of view, the two companies are very similar, to be honest.
But knowing that, does not make me comfortable with the choice and i feel i'm not making the right decision

Comment: YOu could try to make contact privately and share experiences why you each want to leave. Since he/she is leaving this could be an open exchange.

Comment: Do you feel that the manager knows something about company X that you missed and is leaving for that reason?

Comment: Here are several more reasons that they might be changing companies: They want a change of pace, they want a shorter commute, they have a friend at your current company, they prefer the working style at your current company, or they are seeking different responsibilities. There are many reasons that someone might leave a job, and not all are negative reflections on the company.

Can you describe further what makes you feel that you are not making the right decision?

Comment: Joining a team that has no manager can go very wrong if not handled correctly by the organization. This happened to me 6 months after I joined (and to some colleagues a week after being hired) and we were without any direction for a lot of time. I don't consider it a 'no-go' but it is certainly not ideal.

Answer (score 9):

> I would like to a polite way to say "the fact that since my future
>   manager want to join my current company I don't want to accept the
>   offer"

Why would you need/want to say that? You don't owe them any other reason than you've changed your mind.

"Thank you for your time and interest but I've decided not to pursue this opportunity. Please remove me from consideration for this position."